# php substr not working on variable

Tags: php, substr

I have a batch of code that builds a table using php variables.

What I am trying to do is capture the first 3 characters of flight.flightnum flight.flightnum returns BAW111 for example and I want the BAW bit. Easy right? Well I am now php expert but using substr is not working for me at all. Code as follows:

```
<script type="text/html" id="acars_map_row">
<tr class="<%=flight.trclass%>">
<td><a href="<?php echo url('/profile/view');?>/<%=flight.pilotid%>"><%=flight.pilotid%> - <%=flight.pilotname%></a></td>
<td><%=flight.flightnum%></td>
<td><%=flight.depicao%></td>
<td><%=flight.arricao%></td>
<td><%=flight.phasedetail%></td>
<td><%=flight.alt%></td>
<td><%=flight.gs%></td>
<td><%=flight.distremaining%> <?php echo Config::Get('UNITS');?> / <%=flight.timeremaining%></td>
</tr>
</script>
```

I have never worked with these types of variables before, I have tried:

```
<?php $result = "<%=flight.flightnum%>"; echo $result ?> // = BAW111

<?php $result = "<%=flight.flightnum%>"; echo substr($result, 0 ,3) ?> // gives an error and nothing is returned.
```

I'm sure its something obvious but im out of ideas.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Mureinik It doesnt return any rows at all, just a blank table.

Comment: `gives an error`... what error? What does `var_dump($result);` return?

Comment: It returns: string(21) "BAW111"

Comment: so the string(21) bit is obviously the problem @chris85 does it need to be encoded in some way?

Comment: <?php $result = "<%=flight.flightnum%>"; echo substr(trim($result), 0 ,3) ?> returns no results/blank table

Comment: @chris85 preg replace turns blank field for $result but DOES allow the table to be populated with the other data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132122/discussion-between-chris85-and-cloudsurferuk).

Comment: Turns out the transformation is being down clientside, not in php.

Comment: please do @chris85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
<%=flight.flightnum%>
```

is processed client side so your:

```
echo substr($result, 0 ,3)
```

is putting just:

```
<%=
```

into your source (e.g. the first 3 characters). This is breaking the page generation because the mark up is invalid.

You will need to resolve this issue client side after what ever runs the `<%=stuff%>` processing.

Additionally, [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) outputs information about a variable. It will display its value, type, and length. The 21 in this instance was the length of `<%=flight.flightnum%>`.. this also was outputted but whatever is running the `<%=`s (I thought ASP) converted it to the flight value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the variables in PHP tags so that they are parsed.

E.g.

```
<td><?php <%=flight.flightnumber%> ?></td>
```

They are likely appearing as HTML tags as the code is currently.

...

´$result´ is likely to contain a reference to the object. Try wrapping it in quotes first.

```
<?php
$result = "<%=flight.flightnum%>";
echo substr($result, 0 ,3)
?>
```

Comment: Hi @jbes, my bad in the question, it is wrapped in qoutes.